# Custom expandable side menu with animation in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am in the process of learning react however have hit a snag. I need to create side menu that a collapsible with smooth animation in react. I need when expanded the toggle icon to also change but its not working as expected. I have tried this but it collapse and expand all the menu list at once plus the toggle icon only appear at the top menu list only.
When I click expand on one menu list
[image]

and when I click collapse on one menu list

[image]

and that is not the behavior I want. I want one or several menu list can be expanded as long as they have been clicked or collapsed when clicked (toggle).
This is my React Code

```
  function Sidebar() {
  const [open, setopen] = useState(true);
  const toggleOpen = () => {
    setopen(!open);
    console.log(open);
  };
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebarWrapper">
        <div className="sidebarMenu" id="demo_header">
          <h3 className="sidebarTitle" onClick={toggleOpen}>
            User Creation
          </h3>
          <img
            src={open ? collapse_icon : expand_icon}
            alt="Expand"
            className="nav_icons"
          />

          <ul
            id="menu1"
            className={open ? "sidebarList show_menu" : "sidebarList hide_menu"}
          >
            <li className="sidebarListItem active">
              <Home className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText">Home</span>
            </li>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              <GroupAdd className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText"> New users</span>
            </li>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              <PostAdd className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText">Home</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="sidebarMenu" id="demo_header">
          <h3 className="sidebarTitle" onClick={toggleOpen}>
            Main Report
          </h3>
          <img
            src={open ? collapse_icon : expand_icon}
            alt="Expand"
            className="nav_icons"
          />

          <ul
            id="menu2"
            className={open ? "sidebarList show_menu" : "sidebarList hide_menu"}
          >
            <li className="sidebarListItem active">
              <Home className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText">Sales Report</span>
            </li>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              <GroupAdd className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText">Orders Report</span>
            </li>
            <li className="sidebarListItem">
              <PostAdd className="sidebarIcon" />
              <span className="titleText">Stock Report</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}`

export default Sidebar;
and my Css
`
``
`.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background-color: rgb(251, 251, 255);
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.sidebarWrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #555;
}

.sidebarMenu {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarTitle {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #646464;
  padding: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
}
.titleText {
  color: #990000;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.sidebarList {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebarListItem {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.sidebarListItem.active,
.sidebarListItem:hover {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 255);
}
.sidebarIcon {
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-size: 20px !important;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .sidebarListItem {
    display: grid;
  }
  .titleText {
    font-size: 11px;
  }
  .sidebarIcon {
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
  .sidebarTitle {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebarListItem {
    display: grid;
  }
  .titleText {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .sidebarIcon {
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 17px !important;
  }
  .sidebarTitle {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .sidebarListItem {
    display: grid;
  }
  .titleText {
    font-size: 13px;
  }
  .sidebarIcon {
    margin-right: 1px;
    font-size: 19px !important;
  }
  .sidebarTitle {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
}
/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
}
/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
}

.nav_icons {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  filter: invert(76%) sepia(30%) saturate(3461%) hue-rotate(321deg)
    brightness(98%) contrast(91%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
.menuitem {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.hide_menu {
  display: none;
  transition: width 30s ease-in-out;
}
.show_menu {
  display: block;
}
```